# replace substrings between patterns with sed GnuWin32

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed, cmd, gnu-sed

I want to try to find between patterns substrings then replace it

Source example text:

```
bbllaahh pattern1 blaah _SUBSTRING_ blah blaah
bbblah bbllaahh pattern1 blah blaah _SUBSTRING_ blahh  _SUBSTRING_ blaah blahh blah pattern2 blllah blaaah
blahh blllllah _SUBSTRING_ blaah pattern2 blluhhh
```

Expecting:

```
bbllaahh pattern1 blaah _SUBSTRING_ blah blaah
bbblah bbllaahh pattern1 blah blaah _REPLACE_ blahh  _REPLACE_ blaah blahh blah pattern2 blllah blaaah
blahh blllllah _SUBSTRING_ blaah pattern2 blluhhh
```

Patterns is could be different, and could be one or more in string. Source text not be changed except a substring replacement

I found example for unix:

`sed '/pattern1/,/pattern2/'` - doesn't work

`sed '/pattern1/{s/_SUBSTRING_/_REPLACE_/}'` - it's work but I am not sure whether working for pattern2 (`'` was replace `"` for win)

I was try to mixing but it doesn't work:

`sed "/pattern1/,/pattern2/{s/_SUBSTRING_/_REPLACE_/}"`  - doesn't work pattern1

`sed "/pattern1/,{s/_SUBSTRING_/_REPLACE_}/pattern2/"` - doesn't work

Also `_SUBSTRING_` could be instead a one of some special cheractors(like a `"`)

P.S.: This i do in window environment with sed GnuWin32

Answer (score 0):

This may work assuming you intend to find both `pattern1` and `pattern2` on the same line.

```
$ sed '/pattern1.*pattern2/s/_[^_]*_/_REPLACE_/g' input_file
bbllaahh pattern1 blaah _SUBSTRING_ blah blaah
bbblah bbllaahh pattern1 blah blaah _REPLACE_ blahh  _REPLACE_ blaah blahh blah pattern2 blllah blaaah
blahh blllllah _SUBSTRING_ blaah pattern2 blluhhh
```

Comment: In Windows, the prompt is not generally `$`. The OP wished for a Windows cmd.exe solution using the GnuWin32 version of the Stream Editor.

Comment: The solution works is only partially, but anyway is not bad for me at now. I modified code.  `"/patern1.*patern2/s/\"/_REPLACE_/g"` - for a quote  `"/patern1.*patern2/s/_SUBSTRING_/_REPLACE_/g"` - for substring. I forget to write in the source example text this assumption: `bbblah _SUBSTRING_ bbllaahh pattern1 blah blaah _SUBSTRING_ blahh  _SUBSTRING_ blaah blahh blah pattern2 blllah _SUBSTRING_ blaaah` couldn't be outside the pattens. Thanks anyway